# how to index and query dictionary data type in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a record as below:

```
{
   "host":"192.168.1.2",
   "metric_value_string":{"192.168.1.5":0,"192.168.1.4":44,"192.168.1.7":32,"192.168.1.8":1,"192.168.1.6":12}"
}
```

the type of "metric_value_string" is text.

I want to query for specific time range specific host and sort IP base on their value. I dont know what data type should I use. at the moment I used logstash json filter and it make a field for each IP:

```
{
"host":"192.168.1.2",
"metric_value_string":{
    "192.168.1.5":0,
    "192.168.1.4":44,
    "192.168.1.7":32,
    "192.168.1.8":1,
    "192.168.1.6":12,
    "192.168.1.9":12
}
```

"metric_value_string" data type is nested.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hi, Have you tried "ip_range" or "ip" type in a nested manner? you can see this link for more information [Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ip.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution:

```
filter {
         json{
               source => "metric_value_string"
               target => "metric_value_string"
             }
         ruby{
              code => "def filter(event)
                              if !(event.get("metric_value_string")==nil)
                                  arr=Array.net
                                  event.get("metric_value_string").each_pair {|key, value | arr.push(["ip"=>key,"value"=>value])}
                                  event.set("metric_value_string",arr)
                              end
                       return [event]
                        end
                       "
              }
}
```